# Sub-Domain Redirect Loop .htacess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, subdomain

OK so i am getting a redirect loop on subdomains only and i dont see the whats creating the loop

This is a WordPress Multi-Site sub-domain installation and All plugins are disabled everything on the Primary domain works fine.

The loop happens regardless of weather plugins are active or not.

I could use some help with this

Thanks

Notes:

Apache server / Cpanel  / Latest WordPress / Latest ClassiPress Theme /Latest Assorted plugins

```
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;      preload" env=HTTPS

# BEGIN NON-WWW REDIRECT RULES
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# END NON-WWW REDIRECT RULES

# BEGIN SSL REDIRECT RULE
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# END SSL REDIRECT RULE

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# BEGIN IE COMPATABILITY
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    BrowserMatch MSIE ie

    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie

</IfModule>

</FilesMatch>

# END IE COMPATABILITY

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin DISABLED (REMOVE HASHTAG)
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55  .php55 .php
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing your .htaccess with a vanilla generic version downloaded from WordPress?  That will indicate whether the problem is in .htaccess in the first place.

Comment: i am unfamiliar with this .htacess file from wordpress, so no i have not.

Comment: Well, you should